# Confused with the concept with random variable in a sequence of coin tosses

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution

While I am studying probability and random variable, I am kind of mixed up with the following questions in my mind, so I am struggling with getting clear understands about those two questions below:

1. Is each coin toss in a sequence of coin tosses is a single experiment?
2. Does each coin toss in a sequence of coin tosses, for example, 10 times also mean that there are 10 different random variables with the same probability distribution?

Comment: What random variable are you considering?

Comment: A Discfete random variable I think.